# Reset Password not displaying errors inline?

Tags: profile-edit

Using Profile:Edit and am having a hard time getting errors to display inline:

```
{exp:profile:reset_password return="account/reset-confirmed" error_handling="inline"}
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">

  <label>Password Confirm</label>
  <input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
{/exp:profile:reset_password}
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this just not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're missing the variables within the tag to output the errors. See the errors portion of the [docs](http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/profile-edit/#errors) for information about the available variables and conditionals.